# background screen and cursor but that's it

Tags: icons

I am trying to help out my neighbor who was getting an error on his laptop.  He doesn't have his original windows 7 CD, so I used my copy of the boot CD.  When I do this it asks me to select a language, then goes to only the background screen (no icons) and a cursor.  I have tried ctrl-alt-del and nothing.  Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Are you able to install Windows with that CD? Ensure CD works fine.

Comment: Right click on your desktop, hover over view, then press show icons.

Comment: Before I tried the boot cd, it wouldn't even go into safe mode.  When I restart with the boot cd in, it asks for selection of language then goes to only the background screen with no icons and a cursor.  I have tried right clicking on the screen and hitting ctrl-alt-del but neither of these does anything.

Comment: any other suggestions please!!!!